# Django-admin.py runserver not working

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new to python and django and I recently faced some problems.
Django-admin.py runserver does not work (ubuntu 12.04).

Terminal error code:

```
    linas@ubuntu:~$ django-admin.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import AdminMediaHandler, run, WSGIServerException, get_internal_wsgi_application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/static.py", line 95, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop(u"Index of %(directory)s")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 75, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
This is what i get when i use ./manage.py runserver

```
linas@ubuntu:~/Dokumentai/python/FirstBlog$ ./manage.py runserver
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1148c90>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 103, in get_validation_errors
    connection.validation.validate_field(e, opts, f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 14, in validate_field
    db_version = self.connection.get_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 411, in get_server_version
    self.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 306, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 387, in _cursor
    self.connection = Database.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'FirstBlog'")
```

Comment: Is your python path set up correctly?

Comment: Did you run syncdb? Doesn't look like your database has been created.  Try `python manage.py syncdb`

Comment: Any chance you figured this out? I'm getting the exact same issue and have tried everything suggested here.

Answer (score 7):

Use `manage.py` from your project directory

```
cd project
./manage.py runserver
```

Comment: Use `python manage.py runserver` instead. `./manage.py` will always use the system's main Python distribution, and doesn't play well with virtualenvs or user-specific Python distributions.

Comment: because before u need to run: python manage.py syncdb. TO create database, after that runserver.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your models? Also did you created the database?

run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Answer (score 0):

first of al (i hope you have done that) create a directory with the name of your project, then start your django project executing the command: 
python django-admin.py startproject projname
(if it doesnt execute properly drop the keyword "python" and try)
Now run python manage.py runserver from the same directory. If you have installed correctly you wil get:
Validating models
.
.
0 errors found